# SQLiteOpenHelper-Android Confusion

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have couple of question regarding to sqlite-android

1. When is the `onUpgrade` method called in application?
2. Can I have two helper class in one application? 
   if so...
3. then how/when I call second class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onUpgrade is called when  int DATABASE_VERSION of your DBAdapter is higher than the currenly installed one.

Why would you want 2 helper classes. But yes, I suppose you could.